# Redirect all pages except one page to sub-domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I have a index.php in my main domain root

domain.com/index.php

And ive moved my forums which was in the same "root" to a subdomain

forums.domain.com

I need to Redirect everything except the index.php

ive tryed loads of ways and none seem to work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forums.domain.com [L,R]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} animelon\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forums.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If anyone has any ideas that would be great
as for the above codes I would them googling about.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You may use RedirectMatch instead of rewriting, that is, replace all the rewrite block you are showing with:

```
RedirectMatch ^(/(?!index\.php).*) http://forums.domain.com$1
```

You can see the full explanation of the regex on Regexr [here](http://regexr.com?2tvq1). In brief, it sends all the URIs **NOT** beginning with `/index.php` to forums.domain.com.

If you don't need any other rewrite rule, you can turn off rewriting by removing all the lines beginning with "Rewrite" from your .htaccess.

Comment: Hi there so just use RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^(/(?!index\.php).*) http://forums.animelon.com$1 and that's it? sorry not very good at this kind of thing... I tryed the above but it didn't work, Thanks

Comment: Try turning off RewriteEngine (that is, `RewriteEngine off`) and if it doesn't work still, try changing the second directive to `RedirectMatch /(?!index.php)(.+) http://forums.domain.com/$1`

Comment: Can you post an example which is failing to redirect correctly?

Comment: animelon.com/threads/speed-test-please-vote.469 should be forums.animelon.com/threads/speed-test-please-vote.469 even tho the 1st one works its a (bug) it should be just a dead page this is the reason I need to redircet thanks

Comment: Using firebug, I see it redirects- sending an HTTP 301 header- to `Location /threads/speed-test-please-vote.469/` : this means there's probably another Redirect directive parsed before this one.

Comment: Is that this than? http://pastebin.com/8J9JGz6D am very sorry am all new to this. I did try your code with out this but it was the same.

Comment: Definitely: the last RewriteRule (`RewriteRule ^.*$ proxy.php [NC,L]`) gives no chance to anything: it tells to rewrite all addresses to  proxy.php. If disabling the RewriteEngine at first line changes nothing, try renaming the .htaccess file: it means there's something interfering, e.g.: another .htaccess file, the main server config, or even that your .htaccess files are not parsed by the server (which, I noticed, is not Apache but cloudflare-nginx). AFAIK only Apache parses .htaccess files.

Comment: Ok I have got rid of proxy.php to test and added your code same just moves me to forums.animelon.com all the time p.s thanks alot for the help

Comment: hmm kill my site when I remove the proxy part guess am stuck :/ thanks tho

Comment: Ok, I guess you should post another question because we're making too many comments here. In the new question there should be the detailed .htaccess, what happended when you changed the file, and what you tried so far.

Comment: Its ok now mate ive change the way my site is, I was getting alot of problems the way I had it. Thanks alot for your time tho sir.