# Apache redirect all sub pages to home page except specific pages

Tags: apache, apache2

I have a site structure such as this:

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/subpage-a
www.domain.com/subpage-b
www.domain.com/terms
www.domain.com/request-information
```

I am trying to configure an Apache rewrite rule which will point **all** sub pages to the home page, bar specific pages.

Using the example above I would need to redirect all the sub pages of the site to the home page, bar say the `terms` and `request-information` pages.

I have been looking on StackOverflow and I've found a few questions that went unanswered, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326062/redirect-all-pages-except-one-page-to-sub-domain-htaccess) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543697/redirect-all-pages-to-top-level-page). The second link seems to kind of do what I want but I'm not sure how to override my rule for specific pages.

### My configuration

Currently, my Apache file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.domain.co.uk

 ProxyPreserveHost On
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://server:8000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/root/site/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName domain.co.uk
 Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>
```

In an attempt to get this working I appended this, just to see if I could get a sub page to redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName http://www.domain.co.uk/subpage-a
 Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>
```

This didn't work but as there are a lot of sub pages to this site, I really would like more of a catch-all rule which would be ignored for certain sub pages.

Is this possible and does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

### TL;DR

I'm looking for a 'catch-all' style Apache rewrite rule which will  redirect every subpage, bar certain pages to the home page of the domain.

### **EDIT**:

With regards to the answers below I have tried the following:

### Answer #1

I modified my code to look like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName sub.domain.co.uk

 ProxyPreserveHost On
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(terms|request-information)(/.*|)$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://server:8000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/root/site/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName domain.co.uk
 Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.co.uk/
</VirtualHost>
```

However it seems to 404 the pages containing a dash, I can live with this however unfortunately it requires me to list all of the pages I would like to redirect in place of the `terms|request-information` above.

### Answer #2

I must preserve the original re-write rule, multiple re-write rules seem to give me a "This website is not redirecting correctly" message in my browser, I did a copy-and-paste on this code amending the details as necessary but it resulted witg the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the `VirtualHost` section of `www.domain.co.uk` insert this code just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(terms|request-information)(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT:**
Multiple rewrite rules seem to cause a redirection error, only use one.

Comment: Seems this doesn't work as well as I thought. It results in the pages 404'ing - although this isn't much of an issue it seems to then ONLY work for the pages I have typed into the brackets in place of 'terms' etc. This is close but it doesn't fit the bill of a 'catch-all' method

Comment: This is one of the most simple of all the rewrite rules I have written. May I know how your code looks like now and for which URI it didn't work.

Comment: This line is faulty: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://server:8000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/root/site/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]`

Comment: That line works with my original config posted in the question. Do you know what is wrong with it? - It works for numerous other sites we have currently setup

Comment: Honestly I don't know because its not making any sense to me at all.

Comment: Your requirement is to `redirect all the sub pages of the site to the home page` and my answer was just for that requirement. What this super long URL is doing I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.your_domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your_domain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"^/$"
RewriteRule (.+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

This will act as catch all. make sure that redirects set in the httpd.conf commented before using this.

Let us know if that helped you. :)

Comment: Do you know if I will still be able to preserve the "RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://server:8000/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/root/site/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]" rule using this? - I have tried your suggestion but my above rule seems to conflict with it. FYI that above rule is the only way the Apache file knows where to send the request on the file system.

Comment: replacing "$ http://www.your_domain.com/" with your exact url didn't worked for you ?

Comment: Unfortunately this file points the domain to my site, if I remove my previously mentioned RewriteRule, Apache will not know where to send requests for the domain (multiple sites run off this one server, we use Apache to direct the requests to the appropriate areas on the server)